# Does a compile time logb/ilogb exist?

Tags: c++, floating-point

My question stems from the act of trying to find a compile time (constexpr) way to get the exponent of a floating-point number (the reason why is not the topic). ilog/ilogb is the best runtime way (other than bit fiddling or casts/unions). Looking at the disassembly in Visual Studio's implementation doesn't help without any idea what they are even doing in the first place. I was hoping there's a formula (of some sort) to getting the exponent of a float or something to point me in the right direction.

What I'm trying to achieve:

```
constexpr int exponent = ilogb(123.45f);
```

Comment: Plain old repeated division/multiplication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, compile time logarithms do not *portably* exist.

However, some compiler could compute that at compile time (using the [as-if rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/As-if_rule)). GCC would do so, perhaps because by using indirectly [`__builtin_ilogb`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html).

Don't forget a simpler approach: a C++ file can be *generated* at build time (you'll configure your [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool, e.g. [`make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) or [`ninja`](http://ninja-build.org/%C2%A7) to do that). So you could write some script (e.g. in [Python](http://python.org/), [awk](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjb8bXFy4XaAhXESBQKHQwrDaUQFgg7MAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.gnu.org%2Fsoftware%2Fgawk%2F&usg=AOvVaw0YB56hKmgs6OX7Xwh6aStM) or some other scripting language), or even your own other C++ program, generating that constant.

BTW, with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) 7.3 on Linux/x86-64, the following file `jaran.cc`

```
#include <cmath>
int f(void) {
  constexpr int e = ilogb(123.45f);
  return e;
}
```

is compiled into a constant function (as seen with `g++ -S -O -fverbose-asm`)

```
    .type   _Z1fv, @function
_Z1fv:
.LFB253:
    .cfi_startproc
# /tmp/jarann.cc:4: }
    movl    $6, %eax    #,
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

Generating C++ code is a "portable" approach, but of course require to configure your build for that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll look into it.